# Phonegap getting sim information using cordova-plugin-sim

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins

I'm new to mobile development. I'm using PhoneGap and I want to add a feature in my app to get the phone number from the SIM card, both on iOS and Android. I'm using this plugin:

[cordova-plugin-sim](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim)

I'm using this very simple index code to display whatever information I can retrieve from the plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>SIM</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                function onDeviceReady(){
                    window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
                }
                function successCallback(result) {
        document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
                }
                function errorCallback(error) {
        document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p id="simInfo"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This does not display anything. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: above code was working fine for me.. can tell your phonegap version and i am using this plugin .https://github.com/scwl/cordova-plugin-sim/tree/57a76b3

Comment: @vijay i just downloaded the desktop version from the phonegap site yesterday so i'm pretty sure it's the latest version, then i installed node js so i can install plugins, i know that the plugins are installed correctly because i was able to use the barcode scanner with no problem what-so-ever, but thanks for the link of the plugin i'm going to try it

Comment: did you check this "Notice: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see this, this, and this article). Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string."

Comment: @Hiten yes, but it's instructed to show me the raw JSON entry, so even if the phoneNumber string is empty it should give me the rest of the entry, right? in this case absolutely nothing comes out

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing on iOS or Android? On Android 6.0 and above you need to implement.

```
  window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Also looking at your code. In the errorCallback function, result will be undefined.

You need to change this.

```
    function errorCallback(error) {
        document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
    }
```

To this

```
    function errorCallback(error) {
        document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(error);
    }
```

Comment: Edited to add info about result being undefined in the errorCallback function.

Comment: i already tried what you suggested, but still, absolutely nothing displays http://imgur.com/7sO84Q0 i even implemented requestReadPermission and it did not change the outcome

Answer (score 0):

I found this ::

> Notice: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see this, this, and
>   this article). Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string.

I did some changes in code but I got "undefined" message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SIM</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
            function onDeviceReady(){
                window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
            }
            function successCallback(result) {
                document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
                document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result.phoneNumber);
                document.getElementById("carrierName").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result.carrierName);
            }
            function errorCallback(error) {
                document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(error);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        SimInfo :: <p id="simInfo"></p>
        <br />
        Phone Number :: <p id="phone"></p>
        <br />
        Carrier Name :: <p id="carrierName"></p>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

I attached the result image please check this.

[image]

please check this.
Thanks.

Comment: mine still doesn't display anything, i copied your whole code and still, nothing... http://imgur.com/7sO84Q0 may i ask what version of phonegap you're using?

Comment: node version is 7.4.0 and
phonegap version is 6.4.6

Answer (score 0):

It gets numbers saved by user as phone number of the sim. If nothing is saved, it will be empty string. I am using redmi note 3. It is there in settings->sim cards & mobile networks->sim1/2->Edit sim card number